# Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.5.0.201312191422 - ftp console empty

Tags: ftp, console, aptana

I just updated to the version released today, but my ftp console doesn't show anything. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: it seems they withdrew version 3.5.0 and publish 3.4.2 again, as latest release. perhaps too many bugs unsolved. wait for next fine update :) keep up the good work!

Comment: As mentioned, 'they withdrew version 3.5.0 and publish 3.4.2 again' without any kind of notice or information. I have tried a 'fresh' installation of both i386 and x64 versions on Kubuntu on different computers even and they are both problematic. For example you get errors by entering the Preferences and not being able to change any settings. Not to mention, that I lost all my perspectives and theme and all preferences by upgrading from 3.4.2 to 3.5.0 so I had to replace every single file back from a backup. Aptana should take this seriously, as it is not a joke.

Comment: few days ago they released 3.5.0 again, but withdrew it quickly and 3.4.2 is the latest version available, as it never happened. what are they doing? :)

Comment: They did it again. This time I only downloaded the file, only to find out some days later that it disappeared from their downloads once again. And since that day, nothing. If I wasn't so busy with my running projects I would wipe out Aptana, once such behaviour from a development team is unacceptable. I am assured they don't care being criticized negatively and this is another negative. I would like to remind them though that their free product titled Aptana Studio is being used by developers and sometimes by serious ones (not me), that consider software version change a very important thing.

Comment: Same happened with me, thanks @user3139672, uninstalling 3.5 and installing 3.4.2 again worked. Weird release strategy from Aptana... I guess I should stick to Eclipse or Sublime.

Answer (score 0):

I lost "Connections" lind in the Project view under each project.  I found that I had to edit the properties on each project and choose the Web nature.  If I had any other nature enabled such as PHP then the Connections link would disappear.  Messed up my whole morning